# Rewrite: subdomain as username PHP on shared hosting

Tags: apache-2.2, php, shared-hosting

I have the following configuration:

I've setup A record:

### *.mywebsite.com       IN  A       [IP ON HOSTIN - shared]

The rewrite rule for grabbing the subdomain looks like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(^.*)\.mywebsite.com
RewriteRule (.*)  dostuff.php?username=%1
```

When I try to access any subdomain: bla.mywebsite.com I get this: mywebsite.com/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi

Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: Contact your system administrator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you have either existing rules, or the server itself has some defaults.

Comment: How can I check for these rules or should I contact the hosting support?